How can I change default AspNetUserLogins table to MyUserLogins table in Blazor web app on .NET 8, Login with individual account?
I created a Blazor web app with authentication type = Individual Account. It automatically maps to the default ASP.NET tables. Can I change the name of these tables to make it maps with my tables in database?
Blazor web app settings
ASP.NET default tables
I tried changing the ApplicationDbContext, but it does not work:
public class ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>(options)
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("MyUsers");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("MyRoles");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRoleClaim<string>>().ToTable("MyRoleClaims");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim<string>>().ToTable("MyUserClaims");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<string>>().ToTable("MyUserLogins");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>().ToTable("MyUserRoles");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserToken<string>>().ToTable("MyUserTokens");
    }
}


You may find your answer here. Also Check the Specific Microsoft Docs

Since you're using ApplicationUser, you should configure the table mappings with ApplicationUser rather than IdentityUser. Make sure your ApplicationUser class is correctly defined as public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser

[SOLVE]

Update ApplicationDbContext.cs.
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
 public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
 {
 }

 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
 {
     base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

     modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("MyUsers");

     // Rename other Identity tables
     modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("MyRoles");
     modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRoleClaim<string>>().ToTable("MyRoleClaims");
     modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim<string>>().ToTable("MyUserClaims");
     modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<string>>().ToTable("MyUserLogins");
     modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>().ToTable("MyUserRoles");
     modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserToken<string>>().ToTable("MyUserTokens");

     // If you want to rename columns, e.g., rename Id to UserId
     // modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("UserId");
 }
}


Open Package Manage Console and run these 2 command to Update tables in Database
 Add-Migration RenameIdentityTables
 Update-Database




***If you already have your table and don't want to update current table:

Update ApplicationDbContext.cs as above
Update table name in ApplicationDbContextModelSnapshot.cs

